# How to wrap input element inside div in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am following [this link](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html).

**In view I have**

`echo $this->formRow($product->get('name'));`

**and in source it is showing like**

```
<label>Name of the product<input name="product[name]" required="required" type="text" value=""></label>
```

**But I want like this**

```
<div><label>Name of the product</label></div>
<div><input name="product[name]" required="required" type="text" value=""></div>
```

Maybe this question asked somewhere but I am not able to find it.

I am using `php 5.6`.

**EDIT:**

According to the answer I was able to solve this issue.Following the documentation in [this link](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html). I have issue in this part

```
echo $this->formCollection($product->get('categories'));
```

I tried like this

```
echo "<div>".$this->formLabel($this->get('categories'))."</div>";
echo "<div>".$this->formInput($this->get('categories'))."</div>";
```

But it throws fatal error.

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormLabel could not be converted to string in /opt/lampp/htdocs/zend2/module/Test/view/test/index/testform.phtml on line 39

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `$this->formRow`, You can use the below code and can separate the label and input both.

```
echo $this->formLabel($form->get('name'));
echo $this->formInput($form->get('name'));
```

It will output this:

```
<label>Name of the product</label>
<input name="product[name]" required="required" type="text" value="">
```

And then you can use the div tag in `echo`. So here is what you want:

```
echo "<div>".$this->formLabel($form->get('name'))."</div>";
echo "<div>".$this->formInput($form->get('name'))."</div>";
```

Comment: Thanks,Can you send me ref for `formLabel` ?

Comment: @Hiranya check this link: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html#formlabel

Comment: Using above ref I am trying to do same for `echo $this->formCollection($product->get('categories'));`, but how can I make it seperate in `collection`?

Comment: What you exactly looking for?? you asked to separate the label and input. Am I right

Comment: yeah,same way as `name field`,but it is defined with `collection`

Comment: No just look at the answer and use that. No need to use collection.